# Create Action For Running Nodejs inside HTML

Tags: html, node.js

I am new at Node.js

I create a server with node.js I have file like this:

1. Server.js
2. Client.js
3. Index.html

Server configuration is okay. But Inside HTML, I would like to link or an action to run client.js

At HTML, usually we use `<a href="client.js">Link</a>` to link a page.

or

run npm with `node client.js` to run client.js

How I do it at html to run client.js, so if we click a link - client.js will run (the action is same like we do for run at npm `node client.js`)?

**EDIT :**

Oke, it looks like difficult to run client.js inside html with click. I changed my question.

I run node.js. And I open a browser (with anything extension html or js) and I would like to run client.js with a click. How do I do that?

Comment: You could serve the client page (or part of that) by Nodejs with a Framework and a Template Engine.
For example Nodejs + Express + Jade(Pug) or Ejs

Comment: @Zauker Can you explain more or give me link? I thought It was easy. Never header of jade or ejs.

Comment: Well at first I don't know what the client does.
As @youngwind says the better way to Client/Server Dialog could be an Ajax REST Service (or Socket connection).
However you could serve your page by Node too, so you could share some session data for example.
Express is a framework that help to make it easy.
You could handle your routes and endpoints functions.
This is a simple Hello Word example: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html.
Instead use res.send() you could serve your page by a Template Engine.
Ejs:http://www.embeddedjs.com/ or
Jade: http://jade-lang.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have never hear of such thing.

But I think, if you want to change something in server through frontend, http ajax is a good way.

But according to my acquaintance, when server accept a request from frontend, in a general way,it will run some code,such as function, but not js file.

You could run js file through **child_process**, it is a module in node, which use to call the shell in your system.
PS, **shell.js** is a better way if you want to call the shell in nodejs.
see this. https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs

Answer (score 0):

Some server side programming environments work on the basis of having a program, in a file, for each URL that needs to be handled.

Node.js does not work that way.

You write a single server program which handles all the requests and which examines the URL of each one to determine what to do.

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.url);
    if (req.url == "/") {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end("The homepage");
    } else if (req.url == "/client.js") {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end("Whatever you want to do for a request for client.js");
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end("Not found");       
    }   
});
server.on('clientError', (err, socket) => {
    socket.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n');
});
server.listen(8000);
```

While you might store some code in *client.js*, that filename wouldn't be mentioned to the client. The server would just load it like any other module and then conditionally call functions from it.

Comment: your code doesn't worked. http://localhost:8000/client.js I opened up, and client.js is not run. I change my question anyway.

Comment: @ucon89 — That is because that particular code isn't *supposed* to run client.js. It is supposed to demonstrate how to handle URLs using Node.js. The problem of adapting client.js so you can load it as a module and then call a function to trigger it is left to you (not least because we know nothing about the content of client.js). Just put that code at the appropriate point in the if/else.

Comment: Thanks, your code worked when I visit http://localshot:8000/client.js. Even there is a pop up to save the file.